# How to display an image with Pylab from a script in a non blocking way

Tags: python, image, matplotlib

I am writing some iterative image processing algorithm **in a script** (I don't want to be using iPython), and I would like to visualize the image I generate after each iteration. That's very easy to do in Matlab, without blocking the main thread, but I am struggling to do it in Python.

In pylab the **show()** function is blocking and I need to close the window to continue the execution of my script. I have seen that some people use the ion() function, but it has no effect in my case, for example:

```
pylab.ion()
img = pylab.imread('image.png')
pylab.imshow(img)
pylab.show()
```

is still blocking. I also saw people saying that "using draw instead of plot" can solve this. However, I am not using plot but imshow/show, is there something that I am missing here?

On the other hand, the **PIL** also has some display functions, but it seems to generate a temporary image and then display it with imagemagick, so I assume there is no way here to display an image and update it in the same window with this method.

I am using Ubuntu 10.10.

Does anyone know how to do it simply, or do I have to start using something like Qt to have a minimal GUI that I can update easily?

Answer (score 3):

Try using `pylab.draw()` instead of `pylab.show()`.

`pylab.show()` will start a Tk mainloop, hence it is blocking. Whereas `pylab.draw()` will force a draw of figure at that point. Since you are using `pylab.ion()`, figures are created already. But at the end of the script you have to put a `pylab.show()` otherwise figures will be closed when script finishes as there is no mainloop. One side effect is that, you can't interact with the figures until you reach `pylab.show()`.

Comment: thanks, your comment that `using pylab.ion(), figures are created already` helped solved my problem. In other words, it is important do this *before* doing any plotting as far as I understood.

Answer (score 2):

you can try to thread your pylab stuff :

```
import pylab
import threading

pylab.ion()
img = pylab.imread('map.png')

def create_show():
    pylab.imshow(img)
    pylab.show()

thread = threading.Thread(target=create_show)
thread.start()

#do your stuff

thread.join()
```

Comment: This does not work for me. In `do your stuff` I wait for a key pressed, but when I do so the thread does not end. Have to kill the process.